# Help me understand the question (existence of a limit in a function)

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I do not understand what the question is asking. The question goes like this:

> Indicate those conditions on function $f: [0, +\infty) \to
>  \mathbb{R}$, that guarantee the existence of the limit $\lim_{x \to +
>  \infty} f(x)$. Do not forget, that $n$ is a natural number
>   (everywhere).

And then there are a bunch of conditions. I will give three of them as an example.

> - There exists a limit for $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$
> - For any $a \geq 0$, there exists a limit for $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a+n)$
> - For any $a > 0$, there exists a limit for $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(an)$.

I do not quite understand what the question is asking. If I interpret the question in a way that the arguments in those three options, namely $n, a+n, an$ are sequences. For example, $x_n = n, x_n=a+n, x_n=an$, then I can check by Gane's (I am not sure what it is called in English, but that is how it sounds in Russian. It is this definition:

> for any sequence {$x_n$} $\in$ $E$ ($x_n \neq a$) such that $\lim_{n
>  \to \infty} x_n = a \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = A$

definition whether there is a limit.

Let's look at the first example and denote $x_n = n$. We know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = +\infty$ and thus there is a contradiction. Because by Gane's definition we are supposed to have a limit, therefore there is no limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$. But it is given in the exercise, that the function does have a limit...

So I am confused about what this exercise wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each condition you must answer the question: "If this condition is satisfied then is it guaranteed that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists?"

For example the answer concerning the first mentioned condition is: "no". This because we find an easy counterexample in the function that is prescribed by $x\mapsto\sin x$ if $x\notin\mathbb N$ and $x\mapsto 0$ otherwise.

Comment: I see, so for all the natural numbers the output is zero, and so the limit is zero. But if we take the $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$, then we get a wave-like behaviour. So this definition is not a bi-directional one, as is clearly indicated by the one direction arrow.

Comment: You could take the sequence $(x_n)_n$ where $x_n=\frac12\pi+n\pi$. Then sequence $f(x_n)_n$ is $1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1\cdots$ showing that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ does not exist. This in spite of the fact that evidently $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$ (because $n\in\mathbb N$ for every $n$).

Comment: Is it a typo that you have another index $n$? i.e. $(x_n)_n$ and $f(x_n)_n$, I have not seen that notation before

Comment: $(x_n)_n$ is a notation for the sequence $x_1,x_2,\dots$. Then $(f(x_n))_n$ is a notation for the sequence $f(x_1),f(x_2),\dots$. I forgot the outer brackets and wrongly wrote $f(x_n)_n$.

Comment: Thank you drhab

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Am I correct in that, for at least those three options I can construct such function that it does not guarantee that there is a limit for $\lim_{x \to + \infty} f(x)$. For example, for the second option: $x \mapsto \sin x$ if $x \notin (x_n)_n$ and $x \mapsto 0$ if $x \in (x_n)_n$, where $x_n = a + n$ for any $a \geq 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ :)? Looks correct to me.

Comment: your solution for the second option is incorrect. It only shows that the existence of a *fixed*  $a$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(a+n)$ exists does not guarantee the existence of $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$. Here *fixed* should be *any* (or *every*). Hint: have a look at $f(x)$ prescribed by $x\mapsto\sin(2\pi x)$ and note that $f(a+n)$ does not depend on $n$ so that $(f(a+n))_n$ converges for every $a$.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking you which of the three conditions, if fulfilled, is enough for you to conclude that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists.

In other words, you need to answer three sub-questions:

- Is it true that if there exists a limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)$ (in integers), then there exists a limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$?
- Is it true that if, for every $a\geq 0$, there exists the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a+n)$, then there exists the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$?
- Is it true that if, for every $a>0$, there exists the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(an)$, then there exists the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$?

You have to answer each of the three questions separately, either by proving that the statement is true, or by providing a counterexample.